# How to install Magento older version?

Tags: installation, magento-1.9.2.0, installer

I am new to Magento. My theme supports `1.9.2.0` version.
Can somebody please provide me with the download link or documentation to install `1.9.2.0` version?

Comment: I'd suggest installing up-to-date version and updating your theme since there was a lot of security fixes introduced since 1.9.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get almost every magento1 version starting with 1.1 from [this github repo](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror).
You have a [branch](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/branches) for every 1.x release and a [tag](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tags) for each 1.x.y realease.

Answer (score 1):

You can download versions from here, 
https://www.magentocommerce.com/download?_ga=1.4259579.973488315.1467809653

for installation tutorials you can follow below links,
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_installation.htm

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to the link below

https://www.magentocommerce.com/download?_ga=1.181848935.1526311521.1467957873

select Release archives and choose your version and download it.

extract the downloaded files into your current magento working domain and open your domain  in your browser

you will find magento installation wizard

Follow the instructions in the installation wizard.

if u find any difficulties while installing write to us.

Comment: so i got downloader.php file and followed the instruction it started download 1.9.2.4 version.. I wanted to start again but now it is giving me error Magento has been downloaded earlier and redirects  me to index.php which is not present.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install the Magento is the **Composer**.

```
sudo composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/magento2 2.3.0
```

If we want to install the latest version then don't need to put the version at the end of the command. Then command will be:

```
sudo composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/magento2
```

More information can find here: https://www.naveenos.com/2020/12/install-latest-or-old-version-of-magento2-via-composer